# Oracle SQL: GROUP BY and HAVING clause

Tags: sql, oracle, join

I have this table (say TABLE1):

```
ID1 | ID2 | NAME
```

where (ID1, ID2) is the composite PK.

And this another table (say TABLE2):

```
  ID | COD1 | COD2 | DATA | INDEX
```

where ID is the PK.

I need to join this tables on `((TABLE1.ID1 = TABLE2.COD1) AND (TABLE1.ID2 = TABLE2.COD2))`

My problem is that, for each ID of TABLE2, I have many tuples with different INDEX. I only want join the tuple that its INDEX is the MAX of its group (COD1, COD2).

For instance, if I have:

```
ID1|ID2|NAME
10   10 JOSH

ID|COD1|COD2|DATA|INDEX
1   10   10   YES   0
2   10   10   NO    1
3   11   10   OH    0
```

I want to get:

```
ID1|ID2|NAME|DATA
10  10  JOSH  NO
```

I have tried this but it doesn't work:

```
SELECT ID1, ID2, NAME, DATA 
FROM TABLE1 T1 JOIN TABLE2 T2 ON T1.ID1 = T2.COD1 AND T1.ID2 = T2.COD2 
GROUP BY ID1, ID2, NAME, DATA HAVING INDEX = MAX(INDEX)
```

Thanks.

Comment: is it giving any error ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have solved it this way:

```
SELECT ... FROM TABLE1 JOIN 
(SELECT ID1, ID2, NAME, DATA 
FROM TABLE1 T1 JOIN TABLE2 T2 ON T1.ID1 = T2.COD1 AND T1.ID2 = T2.COD2 
GROUP BY ID1, ID2, NAME, DATA HAVING INDEX = SELECT MAX(INDEX) FROM TABLE2 WHERE TABLE1.ID1 = TABLE2.COD1 AND TABLE1.ID2 = TABLE2.COD2
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

This is the generic construct.

```
select field1,field2, etc
from yourtables
join 
(select field1, max(something) themax
 from table1
 where whatever
 group by field1) temp on table1.something = themax
 and table1.field1 = temp.field1
 where whatever
```

The two "where whatevers" should be the same.  You should be able to take it from here.

Answer (score 1):

A slightly different solution:

```
select t1.id1, t1.id2, t1."NAME", t3."DATA"
from table1 t1
left join 
(
    select max("INDEX") as maxindex, cod1, cod2 
    from table2 
    group by cod1, cod2
) tt on tt.cod1 = t1.id1 and tt.cod2 = t1.id2
left join table2 t2 on t2."INDEX" = tt.maxindex;
```

If all tuples have different and unique values INDEX, these example is OK. But if some tuples have the same value, it is necessary to write an additional subquery (e.g. select max(ID) from table2) to determine appropriate lines.

P.S. It's best not to use any keyword for your own tables or columns (e.g. INDEX, DATA ...).

[How To Handle Table Column Named With Reserved Sql Keyword?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11629966/how-to-handle-table-column-named-with-reserved-sql-keyword)

[Got an Oracle Table Named as Reserved Word, Which problems may arise?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4750211/got-an-oracle-table-named-as-reserved-word-which-problems-may-arise)

Answer (score 0):

try

```
SELECT ID1,ID2,NAME
FROM TABLE1
join 
(select ID,DATA, max(Index) themax
 FROM TABLE2
 WHERE (your condition)
 group by ID) temp on table1.Index = themax
 WHERE (your condition)
```